# make textview under another textview and to the right of an image programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I set my layout programmatically because I fill it depending of how much images I get from a request. What I want to do is create two textview at the right of the image, the second below the first. With what I found out on other answers, I end out with my second textview to be overlapping the image and is not below the other textview.

```
    int counter = 0;
    while(mList.size()!=counter)
    {
        RelativeLayout row = new RelativeLayout(context);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));            

        ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(context);
        Bitmap image = getImage(mList.get(counter));
        imgBtn.setImageBitmap(image);
        imgBtn.setId(counter + 1); // Because it need to be a positive integer.
        imgBtn.setBackground(null);
        imgBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        row.addView(imgBtn);

        TextView firstText = new TextView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imgBtn.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        firstText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        firstText.setId(counter+100);
        row.addView(firstText);

        TextView secondText = new TextView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,firstText.getId());
        secondText.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        row.addView(secondText);

       ++counter;
       linlayout.addView(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe linearLayout instead of relative.In this you won't be needing to set counter and id. Instead setTag to the view.To make code more readable.

You can just set the orientation of the row layout and then no need to bother about other params to position the view.

I am not adding the code coz i know you can write it very well ,just change the approach.

Comment: It is true that i don't have anything overlapping, but the textViews arent relative to the image like i want, the two textViews are just one after the other. Is there a way to make the second textview below the first and still at the right of the image using a LinearLayout?

Comment: Use your parent as LinearLayout L1 with orientation horizontal and then add Image to it(L1). Again take a LinearLayout (L2) with orientation vertical, add your both textViews to it (L2) , then add L2 to L1 and you will get your result